# Setting the value of a button with a literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my page, there's an HTML button and I want to set its value in C# using a literal; something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="<asp:literal runat="server" ID="Dico" />" />
```

This doesn't work because the quotes clash in the aspx markup.

How can I set the value of a button with a literal?

Note: for now, I just have the literal that writes the entire HTML markup of the button, like this:

```
Dico.Text = "<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + SomeValue + "\" />";
```

This works because the literal creates the button and sets its value at the same time. But what I want is to use the literal just for the value of the button.

Comment: can you do `button.Text = "html you need to add";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for Value

```
<input type="button" value='<asp:literal runat="server" ID="Dico" />' />
```

If you still want to use Value in Double quotes you must use `runat` and `ID` of literal in single quotes

```
<input type="button" value="<asp:literal runat='server' ID='Dico' />" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, kudos for using `Literal` control!

Quotation problem is easy to fix, as you can use single quotes for html tag attributes:

```
<input type="button" value='<asp:literal runat="server" ID="Dico" />' />
```

However you can just as easy turn the `input` into server-side control by simply adding `runat="server"` and manipulate its properties ad attributes directly in code behind.